# First time installation of SQL Server Management Studio; Getting network path not found error 53

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to start mt first data analysis project, and the guide I am following is using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I installed the SSMS 2019 for the first time on my computer. When I'm trying to Connect to a server for a new database engine and entering a server name, I get the error 53 saying the path was not found.

I think it makes sense, since I'm basically looking for a server that doesn't exist yet. My question is then how do I set up a server? Looking up on Google doesn't seem to help and is only giving me vague answers

Comment: Install the Developer edition if you plan to use Agents, or just the Express otherwise https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: if you want to connect to remote server you have to define SQL Server ports in firewall. @sgy0003